# Need to add custom field like description in shopify collection object (Catalog) programatically

Tags: collections, shopify

I am new to Shopify website customization and I trying to add custom field to collection (catalog page).

Any help on this customization?

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Comment: added custom text in "collection-banner-template.liquid" file but I am not aware of  dynamically add custom text in collection (Catalog page) like Description field.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has support for custom fields called [Metafields](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/metafields). You will need a Metafield editing app like [Metafields Guru](https://apps.shopify.com/metafields-editor-2?surface_detail=metafielld&surface_inter_position=1&surface_intra_position=1&surface_type=search) to add them. Once you add the desired field, you can then use the Metefields in liquid like described in this [blog post](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/110057030-using-metafields-in-your-shopify-theme).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to go
   Settings -> 'Custom data' -> 'Collection'
2. Add new "Add definition"
3. Use this field in theme and Collection